# How to develop android apps in eclipse with gstreamer?

Tags: 12.04, android, gstreamer

is there a good and clear tutorial to make install eclipe with andoid and gstreamer developpement in ubuntu 12.04? when I import the tutorial, that an error "gstreamer can not be resolved " with the import com.gstreamer.GStreamer!!
thanks